# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getChildren')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm Trying to implement google map in react using a library called **google-map-react** ,  I am facing an issue related to google map.There is no error in my syntax, and the error show in file google_map_markers.js:100 here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

export default function HappeningsWorldMap() {
    const defaultProps = {
        center: {
            lat: 10.99835602,
            lng: 77.01502627
        },
        zoom: 11
    };

    const handleApiLoaded = (map, maps) => {
        // use map and maps objects
    };

    return (
        <div className='w-6/12 h-96  mx-2 shadow-xl rounded-xl bg-white flex items-start justify-start flex-col'>
            <p className='text-xl font-semibold px-4 py-2'>Happening Locations</p>
            <div className='w-full  h-full items-center justify-center '>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "I already added my google map key " }}
                    defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
                    defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
                    yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
                    onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => handleApiLoaded(map, maps)}
                >
                    <AnyReactComponent
                        lat={59.955413}
                        lng={30.337844}
                        text="My Marker"
                    />
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I don't get exactly what the error is it because of API's key or the react library

Comment: try removing **<React.StrictMode>)** from your **index.js**

Comment: Or just use a more updated library, since `google-map-react` is quite old and has not been maintained for a long time already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems a [bug](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/issues/1129) in **google-map-react**  to fix it  you should remove `<React.StrictMode>`  in **index.js** or  downgrade react to v17